# Using \frac within a table

Tags: math-mode, tables

Does `\frac` not work from within a table? I need to reproduce the formulae for various methods on this page - [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/object_detection.html). I for example use

```
Normalized Square Difference & \frac{\sum_{x',y'} (A(x',y')-B(x+x',y+y'))^2}{\sum_{x',y'} (A(x',y')-B(x+x',y+y'))^2}\\
```

but I see no fraction in the table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the equation in `$<equation>$`? If that doesn't help, you should post a [complete minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I even tried just a normal \frac{1}{1} instead of the above and it doesnt work.Could you tell me the code for one of these?I'd translate it accordingly

Comment: Try `$\frac{\sum_{x',y'} (A(x',y')-B(x+x',y+y'))^2}{\sum_{x',y'} (A(x',y')-B(x+x',y+y'))^2}$`, i.e. enclose the equation in dollar signs to put them into math mode.

Comment: Or, if most of the table is in math mode, surround the entire table with `\[` and `\]`, and surround the non-math within a `\text{}` macro.

Comment: @rty: Glad it works. I've posted the comment as an answer so you can accept that to remove this question from the "unanswered" list.

Comment: @Jake: Making this an answer would be good.

Comment: @Peter: the cells of a `tabular` are typeset in "text mode" even if the tabular is enclosed in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equations need to be in math mode, so you should surround the equations with dollar (`$`) signs:

```
Normalized Square Difference & $\frac{\sum_{x',y'} (A(x',y')-B(x+x',y+y'))^2}{\sum_{x',y'} (A(x',y')-B(x+x',y+y'))^2}$\\
```