# Using \frac within tabular

Tags: tables, fractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using \frac within a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21049/using-frac-within-a-table)

I'm trying to do that within [CodeCogs](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) renderer, but it don't work:

`\begin{tabular}{cc} \hline \frac{x}{2} & \frac{2}{x} \\ \hline \end{tabular}`

How can I fix that? Thank you!

Comment: Fractions and other mathematical matter have to be in math mode: Enclose the `\frac{}{}` commands in dollar (`$`) signs to put them in math mode. See also the recent question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21049/using-frac-within-a-table, of which this seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$...$` or the tabular column definition

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\def\xstrut{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c >{\xstrut$}c<{$}} \hline 
 $\frac{x}{2}$ & \frac{2}{x} \\ \hline
 $\dfrac{x}{2}$ & \dfrac{2}{x} \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]